# Routing angular app to a specific URI in nginx

Tags: angular, nginx, routes, uri, single-page-application

So,I have an angular app that is to be hosted on a URI like www.xyz.com/abc. I have an EC2 instance in which nginx server is running for the same. The site is working fine and successfully hosted but the issue is when i try to input the URL directly in URL bar it shows 404 error but when I navigate through index.html it works fine.

I tried changing rules and hosting index.html in try_files, but nothing is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

keep base `href` "/"

Below is nginx.conf to route all the request on the same page:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  mysite.com www.mysite.com;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;

        location / {
            try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a LFI vulnerability introduced by this configuration.

Comment: There is a LFI vulnerability introduced by this configuration.
More specifically $uri$args can turn the request /../../../../../etc/passwd into downloading the /etc/passwd file from the host depending on the value of your root directive.

Comment: @user4547088 how would you fix the vulnerability?

Comment: @simon77 If I remember correctly, If you try the URL https://myhost.com/?../../../../etc/passwd, then nginx will try to find the file located at ../../../../passwd from directory specified by the root directive.

Because when using $uri$args, you remove the '?' from the URL

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is to redirect URL to index.html if nothing else has been found. You do this with the directive `try_files`, with something like this:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

I suggest looking at the NGINX configurations made by this website: https://nginxconfig.io/.
It supports serving Angular websites with the "index.html fallback routing", needed by all websites doing internal routing.